# in app purchase timeout error (-1001)

Tags: in-app-purchase

i get a timeout error (-1001) when trying to make an in app purchase. this began happening suddenly after in-app-purchase had been working fine for a while. what happens now is that i see my inventory, complete with prices retreived from apple, but after i attempt a purchase and the following code is executed:

```
    SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment
                    paymentWithProductIdentifier: product.productIdentifier];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment: payment];
```

all i get is a timeout error.

i created a test project with nothing but the storefront supplied by a reliable third party (urban airship) which i'd been using successfully with some alterations in my app. i got the same in app purchase timeout error, which strongly suggests some kind of issue on apple's end (it seems that either my device or my app id have gotten blackballed somehow -- perhaps after i'd uninstalled the app a bunch of times to reset its state -- at least with the sandbox servers). so now the question is what to do about it. any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

problem solved:  it was after all an apple issue. apparently the new app store agreement had gummed up the works. i had to install something via the app store on the device, after which the in-app-purchase was a-okay again. thanks all for your help.

Comment: what was the something you needed to install?

Comment: Can u explain what had done by you,I have the same issue and i am thouroughly annoyed

Comment: hey bugfinder, to clarify: my problem had to do with not having approved apple's new app store agreement. in order to approve it, i had to download an app from the app store -- not a specific app, just any app available through the app store -- which forced me to agree to the new terms, and thereafter my problem was resolved. probably there is another way to go through the agreement approval process, but that was the easiest way i could find. hope that helps.